# How to integrate Springframework with osgi

Tags: java, spring, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am trying to use the springframework with the osgi inside the bundle pom i have imported the dependency like :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, i have configured the plugin for this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Export-Package>org.spring*</Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But, when i am starting my felix i am getting the below exception:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.org.it.processing.serviceintegration [3](R 3.0):
 missing requirement [com.org.it.processing.serviceintegration [3](R 3.0)] osgi.wiring.package; 
 (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.http)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) 
 Unresolved requirements: [[com.org.it.processing.serviceintegration [3](R 3.0)] osgi.wiring.package; 
 (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.http)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1371)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[Device Manager] info: Passive start
```

Please help me.

Comment: You should not Export, but rather `Import-Package` for `org.springframework*`

Comment: You should not. Spring is not designed to work well in a dynamic environment. Even if you make some use-case working, you will find yourself in an endless loop of issues. Additional reading: http://blog.osgi.org/2014/09/how-should-i-use-guicespringblueprint.html

Comment: As Balazs Zsoldos suggested, you should not. You'll find yourself in a never ending loop of hacks and workarounds to make simple things work.

Comment: OSGi have a different Inversion of Control ecosystem. You might want to look for alternative for example:
blueprint or SCR to replace spring xml base configuration
iPOJO for annotation configuration 
If you are comfortable with CDI, PAX-CDI could work too.
See [pax-cdi](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/spaces/PAXCDI/overview)